# Trying to fetch mapi named property?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl, mapi

I am trying to fetch a named property lets say PidNameContentClass which should be a string (PT_STRING8), i am pretty sure it exist in the msg file i am dealing with, because i used mfcmapi and i can see it in their. 
however, in code i am not able to get it using  MAPIPROPS->GetProps nor using OpenProperty, both return MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND.

```
HRESULT hrExists = mapiMessage->OpenProperty(
        PidNameContentClass,
        (LPIID)&IID_IStream,
        0,
        NULL, // MAPI_MODIFY is not needed
        (LPUNKNOWN *)&lpSrcStream);
```

i got the PidNameContentClass tag using mfc mapi when i open the message.
is there a special treatment for named properties such like this one? the code succeeds with tagged properties like PR_MESSAGE_CLASS.
Note: this could be a secured property, but i don't know also how to fetch those or to get there identifiers.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you open the MSG file in MFCMAPI? Did you try to open it in OutlookSpy (click OpenIMsgOnIStg)? Do you hardcode the value of PidNameContentClass or call IMessage::GetIDsFromNames?

Comment: the message is in outlook inbox, i logged in to inbox from mfcmapi, and looked up the message, opened it and hardcoded PidNameContentClass (in code) to the tag i noticed. i did not call GetIDsFromNames, should i use it?

Comment: i used GetIDsFromNames, and its working, thanks.

Comment: Yep, keep in mind that when a message is imported into one of the Outlook folders, the named property tags will be remapped to the store mappings. The tag will not match the values in the MSG file.